# In a normed space, finite linearly independent systems are stable under small perturbations

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Suppose $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ is a normed space and $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is a set of linearly independent elements in X.

> Then $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is stable under a small perturbation in the sense that there exists some small number $\varepsilon>0$ such that for any $\|y_i\| < \varepsilon$ with $1 \leqslant i \leqslant n,$ the all elements of $$\{x_1+y_1,...,x_n+y_n\}$$ are also linearly independent.

I have tried to work only on the unit of $X$ but could not figure out how to overcome this issue. any tips or help is naturally welcome

Comment: I assume $X$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$? If so maybe you can use the continuity of determinant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$p_{x_1,\cdots, x_n}:S\to \mathbb{K},(k_1,\cdots,k_n)\mapsto\|\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_ix_i\|$$
where $S=\{(k_1,\cdots,k_n)\in \mathbb{K}^n|\sum_{i=1}^n| k_i|= 1\}$,
then $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ is linear independent if and only if $p_{x_1,\cdots, x_n}(k_1,\cdots,k_n)>0$ for all $(k_1,\cdots,k_n)\in S$. It is also equivalent to $$p_{x_1,\cdots, x_n}(k_1,\cdots,k_n)\geq \varepsilon$$ on $ S$ for some $\varepsilon>0$ since $S$ is compact.

Now  suppose $p_{x_1,\cdots,x_n}(k_1,\cdots,k_n)\geq 2\varepsilon$ on $ S$ for some $\varepsilon>0$.
Take $y_i$ with $\|y_i\|\leq \varepsilon$($i=1,\cdots,n$), then 
\begin{align*}
p_{x_1+y_1,\cdots, x_n+y_n}(k_1,\cdots,k_n) & =\|\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_ix_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n}k_iy_i\|\\
& \geq p_{x_1,\cdots,x_n}(k_1,\cdots,k_n)- \sum_{i=1}^{n}|k_i|\varepsilon\geq \varepsilon.
\end{align*} Done!